# IPython & Powershell: How to pass commandline arguments to module subcommand?

Tags: powershell, shell, command, ipython

How can I indicate/specify in commandline, that a certain agrument should go to a certain subcommand?

I'm having trouble trying to pass `-c "something"` to `mymodule`, but it goes as argument to `ipython` instead and throws an error.

```
ipython -m mymodule -c "something"
```

So `mymodule` has its own parser and understands how to handle `-c` but its not being fed to it.
Ideally, parenthesis would be apt.

Comment: Doesn't the `ipython` help specify something, like '---', to mark the module's own arguments?

Comment: @hpaulj I got `unrecognized argument` error, could you please elaborate? I'm searching but I feel I don't have the correct terminology.

Comment: What did you search?  I can't access the help myself now.

Comment: `C:\python36> ipython [subcommand] [options] [-c cmd | -m mod | file] [--] [arg]`